# Get The Profit Percentage Change After Each Trade

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to capture the number found in the Profit column (percentage) from the **List of Trades** tab in the Strategy Tester.

This metric is defined by the [TradingView Support page](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000561856-how-are-strategy-tester-report-values-calculated-and-what-do-they-mean/) as:

> **Profit**
>
> The profit per trade and the gain/loss percentage of that
> trade.

Here is the closest I have been able to get:

```
pos_size_change = strategy.position_size != strategy.position_size[1]

equity_1 = valuewhen(pos_size_change,strategy.equity,1)
equity_0 = valuewhen(pos_size_change,strategy.equity,0)

pct_equity_change = (equity_0/equity_1-1)*100

plot(pct_equity_change)
```

The numbers I get when plotting follow the Strategy Tester closely, but they are not identical (sometimes they are).

E.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function to return the profit of a given trade. We can substitute in a trade number with strategy.clossedtrades, which will return the last trade until a new one is complete, or you can ask of it a trade number as you please.

```
tradePercentProfit(trade_num) =>
    endP = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(trade_num-1) * math.abs(strategy.closedtrades.size(trade_num-1))
    prof = strategy.closedtrades.profit(trade_num-1)
    profitInPercent = prof / endP *100

perc = math.round(tradePercentProfit(strategy.closedtrades), 2)

plot(tradePercentProfit(strategy.closedtrades))
```

Cheers and best of luck with your trading and coding

Comment: Thanks @Bjorgum! I'm getting some nonsensical numbers using this as provided. Please see screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdx3s.png - I'm guessing I'm misusing it somehow. Thanks =)

Comment: Nonsensical indeed! Not sure what I gave you there sorry about that. I edited the answer with a new function

Comment: Ah using  `strategy.closedtrades.profit` works very well (better than my original method)! I just have one issue - it's outputting positive values even if trade was a loss. Do you think you could possibly update to so that it gives accurate numbers in that regard? Thanks so much. =)

Comment: Boom that did it - excellent!

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like TradingView calculation is right.

Percentage = 100*(Sold price - bought price)/bought price

So, if you do 100*(18.471-18.707)/18.707 = 1.261

I am not sure what is your commission setting. It is possible that TradingView calculation isn’t considering commission.

Also, I think your method isn’t right to use entire equity.

Even if traded equity is 100%, there are some small issues is strategy calculation such as commission is not considered for calculating trade-able quantity.